# adding line breaks in tikz and colour to diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I have the minimum about of code to produce what I want but am unsure

1. how to split the text into separate lines, for example the examples below the definitions.
2. Colour the ovals.

   ```
     \documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{book}

     \usepackage{tikz}
     \usepackage{amsfonts} 
     \usepackage{amssymb}

     \newcommand{\x}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}

     \begin{document}

     \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily, scale=0.8]
     \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 2] in {Natural \(\x{N}\) ,Whole numbers \  (\x{Z}\) ,Rational \( \x {Q} \), Real algebraic \( \x{A} \), Real \(\x{R} \) \\   ($\pi$)}
      {\draw (-\Y,-\Y/2) circle ({1.5*\Y} and \Y);
      \node at (1-2*\Y,-1.1*\Y) {\X}; }
      \draw ([xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]current bounding box.south west)
      rectangle ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]current bounding box.north east);
      \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {Types of numbers};
      \end{tikzpicture}

      \end{document}
   ```

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have multiline node contents you need to add `align=center` (or left or right) to the node. To color the ellipses, draw them from big to small and add `fill=<color>`. I included the color as an additional variable in the for loop.

Note: You need braces (`{...}`) for your list of numbers because of the commas.

[image]

```
  \documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{book}

  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{amsfonts} 
  \usepackage{amssymb}

  \newcommand{\x}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily, scale=0.9]
  \foreach \X/\col [count=\N, evaluate=\N as \Y using 7-\N] in {Real $\x{R}$\\{$\pi,e,\ln2$}/blue, Real algebraic $\x{A}$\\{$\sqrt{5}, \varphi, \sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt{3}$}/green, Rational $\x{Q}$\\{$-\frac{1}{2}, .7, .3\overline{3}$}/yellow, Integers $\x{Z}$\\{$-5,0,12$}/orange, Natural $\x{N}$\\{$1,2,3$}/red}
   {\draw[fill=\col!30] (-\Y,-\Y/2) circle ({1.5*\Y} and \Y);
   \node[align=center] at (1-2*\Y,-1.1*\Y) {\X}; }
   \draw ([xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]current bounding box.south west)
   rectangle ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]current bounding box.north east);
   \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {Types of numbers};
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! was only hoping for some advise and you provided exactly what I needed so quickly! I'll just have to read over everything so I can learn from it.

Comment: @PaulA: I added some comments to the solution. Let me know if anything needs clarification.